# Cheapest and fastest method to lower the soil pH for potatoes?

Tags: soil-amendment, potatoes, ph

I am going to plant some potatoes in two/three weeks, but my soil's pH is around 6.8, which is not very suitable for them. I would like to know if there is a way to lower the pH in two/three weeks in a relatively cheap way.

The soil is more clay than sand; I sprinkled some sand bags and cow dung fertilizer so it became a little better, but it still not a perfect balance. I would like to plant Japanese Baron potatoes directly into the soil. Its just a one row 7m x 1m area

Comment: Tell us more about the soil....clay?  sand?  lots of organic matter or not?

Comment: We also need more information about your plans. How big an area? Directly in the ground, or in a container or raised bed?

Comment: thanks for the comments! Soil is more clay than sand, I sprinkled some sand bags and cow dung fertilizer so it became a little better, but it still not perfect balance. I would like to plant Japanese Baron potatoes and its directly to the soil. Its just a one row 7m x 1m area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://hort.extension.wisc.edu/articles/reducing-soil-ph/

Mentions sulfuric acid, aluminum sulfate, and elemental sulfur.

They recommend against home gardeners using sulfuric acid. Some other sources mention adding vinegar in your irrigation water as a possible approach, though I question how long the effect would last. Still, should also be quick-acting, and relatively safe.

For the remaining two, as might be expected, cheapest is not fastest and fastest is not cheapest. Ammonium sulfate acts faster as it is more soluble, while sulfur is cheaper.

Iron sulfate is more hazardous to handle than ammonium sulfate, but gets you away from the potential problem of excess aluminum causing problems in your soil.

Comment: thanks! This was very helpful! I think I'm gonna use sulfate and vinegar combination for my problem. Also can get Pyroligneous acid more cheaper than vinegar, so maybe use that instead